# Stream.io Chat API - Member state omitted from queryChannels response

Tags: getstream-io

When I do the following:

```js
      const queryChannelsResponse = await this.client.queryChannels(
        { id: channelId },
        { last_updated_at: -1 },
        { state: true },
```

This does not include the members. How am I able to get the member information?

I am writing a webhook and I want it to send a push notification (I am currently sending these myself via expo) to all offline users.

I am migrating from pusher chatkit which is now being discontinued. They had a new_message_users_offline hook for this purpose.

In the message.new webhook payload in the documentation the members are present but they are not present in the request body:

```
{
    "type": "message.new",
    "cid": "messaging:394f36fd-d512-4f2b-a785-ab8dfe82af49",
    "message": {
        "id": "f73ee1a8-f6fd-450b-bc64-0840b4df8fd9-2b4908ad-e267-4c48-8f41-8c26c8f769ce",
        "text": "Ffddf",
        "html": "<p>Ffddf</p>\n",
        "type": "regular",
        "user": {
            "id": "f73ee1a8-f6fd-450b-bc64-0840b4df8fd9",
            "role": "user",
            "created_at": "2020-04-06T14:06:37.979584Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-04-06T19:45:39.556842Z",
            "last_active": "2020-04-06T19:45:39.54939Z",
            "banned": false,
            "online": true,
            "name": "Mark Everett",
            "image": "https://8dc-user-files-dev.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/MEMBER_PROFILE_IMAGE-f73ee1a8-f6fd-450b-bc64-0840b4df8fd9.png?v=6"
        },
        "attachments": [],
        "latest_reactions": [],
        "own_reactions": [],
        "reaction_counts": null,
        "reaction_scores": {},
        "reply_count": 0,
        "created_at": "2020-04-06T19:51:14.114803Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-06T19:51:14.114803Z",
        "mentioned_users": []
    },
    "user": {
        "id": "f73ee1a8-f6fd-450b-bc64-0840b4df8fd9",
        "role": "user",
        "created_at": "2020-04-06T14:06:37.979584Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-06T19:45:39.556842Z",
        "last_active": "2020-04-06T19:45:39.54939Z",
        "banned": false,
        "online": true,
        "channel_unread_count": 0,
        "channel_last_read_at": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "total_unread_count": 0,
        "unread_channels": 0,
        "unread_count": 0,
        "image": "https://8dc-user-files-dev.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/MEMBER_PROFILE_IMAGE-f73ee1a8-f6fd-450b-bc64-0840b4df8fd9.png?v=6",
        "name": "Mark Everett"
    },
    "watcher_count": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-04-06T19:51:14.121213459Z",
    "channel_type": "messaging",
    "channel_id": "394f36fd-d512-4f2b-a785-ab8dfe82af49"
}
```

My plan is do do something like this:

```js
  public async getOfflineUserIds(channelId: string): Promise<string[]> {
    try {
      // Get the channel
      const queryChannelsResponse = await this.client.queryChannels(
        { id: channelId },
        { last_updated_at: -1 },
        { message_limit: 0, limit: 1, state: true},
      )
      const channel = queryChannelsResponse[0]

      console.log('channel: ', channel)

      // Get the channels members
      const userIds: string[] = []
      // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
      for (const index in channel.state.members) {
        userIds.push(channel.state.members[index].user_id)
      }
      console.log('userIds:', userIds)

      const queryUsersResponse = await this.client.queryUsers(
        { id: { $in: userIds } },
        { last_active: -1 },
        {},
      )

      console.log('queryUsersResponse:', queryUsersResponse)

      // Work out who is offline/online
      const offlineUserIds = queryUsersResponse.users
        .filter(u => !u.online)
        .map(u => u.id)

      return offlineUserIds
    } catch (err) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(
        'Error getting offline users for channel.',
        err,
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your plan looks great! We just checked your channel and it doesn't appear to have any members associated with it.

You can add members to a channel that has been created with 

channel.addMembers()

Comment: I will look into this, I assumed considering I am having a two way conversation then the channel would have two members.

Comment: I now create the channel and add the members on the server as this works best for my use case and the members are now present in the places I would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now resolved.

I did not add the members to the channel with `channel.addMembers`. I create and add members on the server as this works perfectly for my use case.

If it helps anyone I ended up with these two methods:

```js
  public async getChannelUserIds(channelId: string): Promise<string[]> {
    try {
      const queryChannelsResponse = await this.client.queryChannels(
        { id: channelId },
        { last_updated_at: -1 },
        { message_limit: 0, limit: 1, state: true },
      )
      const channel = queryChannelsResponse[0]

      const userIds = Object.keys(channel.state.members)
      console.log('userIds:', userIds)

      return userIds
    } catch (err) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(
        `Error getting user ids for channel ('${channelId}').`,
        err,
      )
    }
  }
```

```js
  public async getOfflineUserIds(userIds: string[]): Promise<string[]> {
    try {
      const queryUsersResponse = await this.client.queryUsers(
        { id: { $in: userIds } },
        { last_active: -1 },
        {},
      )

      console.log('queryUsersResponse:', queryUsersResponse)

      const offlineUserIds = queryUsersResponse.users
        .filter(u => !u.online)
        .map(u => u.user_id)

      return offlineUserIds
    } catch (err) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(
        `Error getting offline user ids from ('${JSON.stringify(
          userIds,
          null,
          2,
        )}').`,
        err,
      )
    }
  }
```

And then in my webhook I:

```js
@Post('stream/messages')
  public async onReceive(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Headers('x-signature') signature: string,
    @Body() body: any,
  ) {
    try {
      console.debug('webhooks-stream.messages.onReceive')
      this.chatService.verifyWebhook((req as any).rawBody, signature)

      console.log('DEBUG WEBHOOK BODY', JSON.stringify(body, null, 2))

      switch (body.type) {
        case 'message.new': {
          const offlineMemberIds = await this.chatService.getOfflineUserIds(
            body.members.map(member => member.user_id),
          )

      ...
```